# Sleak SWT tool, Device is not tracking resource allocation

Tags: testing, swt

I'm having trouble in testing an RCP application with Sleak because it does not display anything, it only shows the message "WARNING: Device is not tracking resource allocation".
I've setup Sleak from [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/17/finding-swt-leaks-with-sleak/) tutorial and I don't know what's wrong.
Does anyone know a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleak in RCP: Device is not tracking resource allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810556/sleak-in-rcp-device-is-not-tracking-resource-allocation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the correct [version](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php)? Can you see the sleak view in your RCP-application? If not make sure it's in your launch configuration. Also double check that you have set the

> org.eclipse.ui/debug=true
>   org.eclipse.ui/trace/graphics=true

correct in the tracing tab. There are properties with similar names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes i have the correct version and the sleak view shows up in my RCP-App, and with the lunch configuration i've checked and a multi-checked (i tried all the possible combinations that mite work).
Unfortunately i could not make it work.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.misc.Policy.DEBUG_SWT_GRAPHICS = true;
org.eclipse.ui.internal.misc.Policy.DEBUG_SWT_DEBUG = true;
```

before

```
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
```

This will create in Workbench.createDisplay() method
new Display with data tracking.