# Sleak in RCP: Device is not tracking resource allocation

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, sleak

I have tried to make Sleak work on my Indigo RCP application. I have followed the steps on [this guide](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/17/finding-swt-leaks-with-sleak/). I.e. I have installed the plugin, added the swt tools plugin to current plugins, added the required plugins, modified the tracing options, and added the view in my application with `folder.addView("org.eclipse.swt.tools.views.SleakView");`

The view does indeed show up but I keep getting the error 'Device is not tracking resource allocation' when I try to use it.

I have tried the answers to older questions in stackoverflow on the matter, but had no luck

[Sleak (SWT & RCP) : Device is not tracking resource allocation (eclipse 4.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460698/sleak-swt-rcp-device-is-not-tracking-resource-allocation-eclipse-4-3)

[Sleak SWT tool, Device is not tracking resource allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108430/sleak-swt-tool-device-is-not-tracking-resource-allocation)

I have explicitly checked that the .options file loaded in the debug configuration does indeed have both the tracing options needed.

Any additional ideas?

Comment: have you tried it with more recent Eclipse, i.e. is this a bug in 5 year old Eclipse that is long since fixed? How is the " .options file loaded in the debug configuration " do you mean in the Tracing tab you have the correct options checked, or are you passing the .options in a different way?

Comment: When you enable tracing and debug in trancing tab it explicitly tells the location on the .options file when you run it on the console (some tutorials even told you to modify it manually to add the tracing options). I have checked that the options file loaded in the debug configuration contains both tracing lines.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce, can you confirm your versions of the sleak and swt plug-ins, and the OS platform you are running on?

Comment: I have created a fresh 3.7 Indigo install and with the template Mail app I was able to get it to work on Linux x64. The SWT version is 3.7.2.v3704f and the sleak version is 3.7.0.201103231601. Does it work for you with the template mail app?

Comment: Tested on mail app, it does indeed work. Replicating same steps on my RCP app does not work. I can confirm I'm using the versions you posted on both SWT and Sleak (SWT.tools) plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't set these properties correctly:

```
org.eclipse.ui/debug=true
org.eclipse.ui/trace/graphics=true
```

[image]

Comment: I have correctly set them, as explained in the comments above. The options work for the mail app, but not for the app I want to test for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem recently, and managed to find a solution.  Here's what I found, who knows it might help you.

On RCP startup, there's a call to `PlatformUI.createDisplay()`, which chains to a call to `Workbench.createDisplay()`.  That's the exact point where the debug settings needed by Sleak are properly read and set.

What happened on our software was that a call to `Display.getDefault()` was made BEFORE the above call to `PlatformUI.createDisplay()`.  It caused the creation of a new Display object, which was set as the default.  This creation did not read and set the debug settings.

By the time our code got to the `PlatformUI.createDisplay()` call, it didn't actually create a new Display.  Instead, it returned the previously-created, not-debug-friendly one.  Thus leading Sleak into warning about "device not tracking resource allocation".

Adding a breakpoint at the method `Display.register (Display display)` helped us identifying the early creation origin and properly change it.